# how to locate coredump function with -O2

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

when the application compiled with -O2 crash, how to locate the function or the code line that make the application crash?

Comment: A program compiled with `-O2` can be debugged, have you missed the `-g` option?

Comment: I compiled with -g -O2, but when the application crash on the production environment, it's hard to locate the problem.

Comment: I mean the symbol may be disorder. I am trying to use addr2line but it doesn't work.

Comment: It would be harder to debug optimized programs, based on my experiences, we need to read the disassembly time by time.

Comment: Thanks, I am wondering if there is an elegant way to debug with -O2.

Comment: @tungfaifong Elegant? No.  Possible? Yes, but it helps a lot to understand the assembly code generated by the compiler.

Comment: note that if the crash was due to stack corruption then the core dump might be corrupted too

Answer (score 0):

> when the application compiled with -O2 crash, how to locate the function or the code line that make the application crash?

In *exactly* the same way as you would for an application compiled without `-O2`.

> when the application crash on the production environment, it's hard to locate the problem.

Your first step should be to arrange for the production environment to save a `core` dump somewhere, or at least to print crashing address (often logged in `/var/log/messages` or the like).

Once you have a `core`, you can use debugger, e.g. `gdb a.out core` and then `where` command will list functions leading to the crash.

If you want file and line info, you need to build `a.out` with the `-g` flag (in addition to `-O2`).

If you don't have a core, but do have the crashing address, then `addr2line -fe a.out $address` should give you the function name.